# Append text from one table to another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Got a small question in which I can't wrap my head around..

I have 2 tables, 1 table where there is a Youtube Link i need to append to another column in table 2. But not every record has a Youtube link, which means I need to check if in both tables the names are the same (WHERE name1 = name2?) But how can I append text to already existing text in table 2? Something like this?

```
UPDATE table2 SET text2 = (text2 + '/n' + table1.text1) WHERE name1 = name2?
```

If someone could help me, would be awesome!

EDIT:

So I fumbled a bit with the queries:

```
SELECT
'Kleding'.'Naam', 
'jos_virtuemart_products_nl_nl'.'product_name', 
CONCAT_WS('/n', 'jos_virtuemart_products_nl_nl'.'product_desc', 'Kleding'.'Youtube_link')
FROM
    'jos_virtuemart_products_nl_nl' as 't2' 
INNER JOIN 'Kleding' as 't1' 
ON 't2'.'product_name' = 't1'.'Naam';
```

But this query is incorrect for some strange reason. I cannot find why it is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can [use `INNER JOIN` in `UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html):

```
UPDATE
    table2 as t2 INNER JOIN table1 as t1 ON t2.name = t1.name
SET
    t2.text2 = CONCAT_WS('/n', t2.text2, t1.text1);
```

**P.S.:** Maybe by `'/n'` you mean `'\n'` ?

**P.P.S:** Before any major data change operation I suggest you [to backup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/backup-and-recovery.html) your database.

---

**UPDv1:**

Test your end resultset with `SELECT`:

```
SELECT
    `t1`.`name` as `t1-name`,
    `t2`.`name` as `t2-name`,
    CONCAT_WS('/n', `t2`.`text2`, `t1`.`text1`) as `changes`
--  ^ here you will see what comes up
FROM
    `table2` as `t2` INNER JOIN `table1` as `t1` ON `t2`.`name` = `t1`.`name`
-- WHERE possibly more conditions to meet your requirements
```

If you manage te get proper resultset with additional `WHERE` conditions, then move them to the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Yeah this looks like it.. Altough I had a small problem, not every entry has a youtube link, sometimes it's empty or sometimes it's 0, do I do this right?:

UPDATE
    table2 as t2 INNER JOIN table1 as t1 ON t2.name = t1.name WHERE t2 != 0 OR NULL
SET
    t2.text2 = CONCAT_WS('/n', t2.text2, t1.text1);

Comment: @HuubS Try to `SELECT` first, look at the data. If it is looks like you want to see it, then `UPDATE`. I'll change my post with the `SELECT` statement asap.

Comment: Hm, I get an empty row. Maybe it's better to use the actual database table names.

1 Database, 2 tables: Clothing and jos_virtuemart_products. I want entry's from Clothing to jos_virtuemart_products append to the prod_desc, but only where the name is the same.

SELECT Clothing.Name, jos_virtuemart_products.product_name, CONCAT_WS('/n', Clothing.Youtube_link, jos_virtuemart_products.prod_desc) as 'changes'
FROM Clothing INNER JOIN jos_virtuemart_products ON Clothing.Name = jos_virtuemart_products.product_name;

Comment: I get empty rows the whole time :(